# Transcribing audio from amazon connect & (Kinesis video Strems) using google cloud speech to text

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-speech, amazon-connect, transcription, amazon-kinesis-video-streams

1. The transcription is not as good as it should be.
2. The transcription only works when the language code is "en-US".
3. I don't get any results when i set language code to "en-IN".

Here is my java code

```
package com.amazonaws.transcribestreaming;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import com.amazonaws.kvstranscribestreaming.KVSStreamTrackObject;
import com.amazonaws.kvstranscribestreaming.KVSUtils;
import com.google.api.gax.rpc.ClientStream;
import com.google.api.gax.rpc.ResponseObserver;
import com.google.api.gax.rpc.StreamController;
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1p1beta1.RecognitionConfig;
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1p1beta1.SpeechClient;
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1p1beta1.SpeechRecognitionAlternative;
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1p1beta1.StreamingRecognitionConfig;
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1p1beta1.StreamingRecognitionResult;
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1p1beta1.StreamingRecognizeRequest;
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1p1beta1.StreamingRecognizeResponse;
import com.google.protobuf.ByteString;
import com.google.protobuf.Duration;

public class InfiniteStreamRecognize {

  private static final int STREAMING_LIMIT = 290000; // ~5 minutes

  public static final String RED = "\033[0;31m";
  public static final String GREEN = "\033[0;32m";
  public static final String YELLOW = "\033[0;33m";

  // Creating shared object
  private static volatile BlockingQueue<byte[]> sharedQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<byte[]>();

  private static int restartCounter = 0;
  private static ArrayList<ByteString> audioInput = new ArrayList<ByteString>();
  private static ArrayList<ByteString> lastAudioInput = new ArrayList<ByteString>();
  private static int resultEndTimeInMS = 0;
  private static int isFinalEndTime = 0;
  private static int finalRequestEndTime = 0;
  private static boolean newStream = true;
  private static double bridgingOffset = 0;
  private static boolean lastTranscriptWasFinal = false;
  private static StreamController referenceToStreamController;
  private static ByteString tempByteString;
  private static boolean breakTranscription = false;


  public static String convertMillisToDate(double milliSeconds) {
    long millis = (long) milliSeconds;
    DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat();
    format.setMinimumIntegerDigits(2);
    return String.format(
        "%s:%s /",
        format.format(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)),
        format.format(
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis)
                - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis))));
  }

  /** Performs infinite streaming speech recognition */
  public static void infiniteStreamingRecognize(String languageCode, KVSStreamTrackObject kvsStreamTrackObject, String contactId) throws Exception {
      
    // AWS Input buffering
    class AWSAudioBuffer implements Runnable {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        try {
            byte[] data;
            ByteBuffer audioBuffer = KVSUtils.getByteBufferFromStream(kvsStreamTrackObject.getStreamingMkvReader(),
                    kvsStreamTrackObject.getFragmentVisitor(), kvsStreamTrackObject.getTagProcessor(), contactId, kvsStreamTrackObject.getTrackName());
            do{
                data = new byte[audioBuffer.remaining()];
                audioBuffer.get(data);
                
                sharedQueue.put(data.clone());
                audioBuffer = KVSUtils.getByteBufferFromStream(kvsStreamTrackObject.getStreamingMkvReader(),
                        kvsStreamTrackObject.getFragmentVisitor(), kvsStreamTrackObject.getTagProcessor(), contactId, kvsStreamTrackObject.getTrackName());
                //expensive op
                kvsStreamTrackObject.getOutputStream().write(data);
                
            }while(data.length>0);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("kvs interrupted, "+e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            // break transcription if no audio available
            breakTranscription = true;
            try {
                System.out.println("Closing the audiofile.");
                kvsStreamTrackObject.getOutputStream().close();
            } catch (IOException e2) {
                System.out.println("Error while closing file:-- "+e2.getMessage());
            }
        }
        
      }
    }

    // Creating microphone input buffer thread
    AWSAudioBuffer awsRunnable = new AWSAudioBuffer();
    Thread awsAudioThread = new Thread(awsRunnable);
    
    // Response observer
    ResponseObserver<StreamingRecognizeResponse> responseObserver = null;
    try (SpeechClient client = SpeechClient.create()) {
        ArrayList<String> languageList = new ArrayList<> ();
        languageList.add("en-IN");
        languageList.add("hi-IN");
      ClientStream<StreamingRecognizeRequest> clientStream;
      responseObserver =
          new ResponseObserver<StreamingRecognizeResponse>() {

            ArrayList<StreamingRecognizeResponse> responses = new ArrayList<>();

            public void onStart(StreamController controller) {
              referenceToStreamController = controller;
            }

            public void onResponse(StreamingRecognizeResponse response) {
              responses.add(response);
              StreamingRecognitionResult result = response.getResultsList().get(0);
              Duration resultEndTime = result.getResultEndTime();
              resultEndTimeInMS =
                  (int)
                      ((resultEndTime.getSeconds() * 1000) + (resultEndTime.getNanos() / 1000000));
              double correctedTime =
                  resultEndTimeInMS - bridgingOffset + (STREAMING_LIMIT * restartCounter);

              SpeechRecognitionAlternative alternative = result.getAlternativesList().get(0);
              if (result.getIsFinal()) {
                System.out.print(GREEN);
                System.out.print("\033[2K\r");
                System.out.printf(
                    "%s: %s [confidence: %.2f]\n",
                    convertMillisToDate(correctedTime),
                    alternative.getTranscript(),
                    alternative.getConfidence());
                isFinalEndTime = resultEndTimeInMS;
                lastTranscriptWasFinal = true;
              } else {
                System.out.print(RED);
                System.out.print("\033[2K\r");
                System.out.printf(
                    "%s: %s", convertMillisToDate(correctedTime), alternative.getTranscript());
                lastTranscriptWasFinal = false;
              }
            }

            public void onComplete() {}

            public void onError(Throwable t) {}
          };
      clientStream = client.streamingRecognizeCallable().splitCall(responseObserver);

      RecognitionConfig recognitionConfig =
          RecognitionConfig.newBuilder()
              .setEncoding(RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16)
              .setLanguageCode(languageCode)
              .addAllAlternativeLanguageCodes(languageList)
              .setSampleRateHertz(8000)
              .build();

      StreamingRecognitionConfig streamingRecognitionConfig =
          StreamingRecognitionConfig.newBuilder()
              .setConfig(recognitionConfig)
              .setInterimResults(false)
              .build();

      StreamingRecognizeRequest request =
          StreamingRecognizeRequest.newBuilder()
              .setStreamingConfig(streamingRecognitionConfig)
              .build(); // The first request in a streaming call has to be a config

      clientStream.send(request);

      try {
        
          awsAudioThread.start();

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        while (true) {

          long estimatedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;

          if (estimatedTime >= STREAMING_LIMIT) {

            clientStream.closeSend();
            referenceToStreamController.cancel(); // remove Observer

            if (resultEndTimeInMS > 0) {
              finalRequestEndTime = isFinalEndTime;
            }
            resultEndTimeInMS = 0;

            lastAudioInput = null;
            lastAudioInput = audioInput;
            audioInput = new ArrayList<ByteString>();

            restartCounter++;

            if (!lastTranscriptWasFinal) {
              System.out.print('\n');
            }

            newStream = true;

            clientStream = client.streamingRecognizeCallable().splitCall(responseObserver);

            request =
                StreamingRecognizeRequest.newBuilder()
                    .setStreamingConfig(streamingRecognitionConfig)
                    .build();

            System.out.println(YELLOW);
            System.out.printf("%d: RESTARTING REQUEST\n", restartCounter * STREAMING_LIMIT);

            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

          } else {

            if ((newStream) && (lastAudioInput.size() > 0)) {
              // if this is the first audio from a new request
              // calculate amount of unfinalized audio from last request
              // resend the audio to the speech client before incoming audio
              double chunkTime = STREAMING_LIMIT / lastAudioInput.size();
              // ms length of each chunk in previous request audio arrayList
              if (chunkTime != 0) {
                if (bridgingOffset < 0) {
                  // bridging Offset accounts for time of resent audio
                  // calculated from last request
                  bridgingOffset = 0;
                }
                if (bridgingOffset > finalRequestEndTime) {
                  bridgingOffset = finalRequestEndTime;
                }
                int chunksFromMs =
                    (int) Math.floor((finalRequestEndTime - bridgingOffset) / chunkTime);
                // chunks from MS is number of chunks to resend
                bridgingOffset =
                    (int) Math.floor((lastAudioInput.size() - chunksFromMs) * chunkTime);
                // set bridging offset for next request
                for (int i = chunksFromMs; i < lastAudioInput.size(); i++) {
                  request =
                      StreamingRecognizeRequest.newBuilder()
                          .setAudioContent(lastAudioInput.get(i))
                          .build();
                  clientStream.send(request);
                }
              }
              newStream = false;
            }

            tempByteString = ByteString.copyFrom(sharedQueue.take());

            request =
                StreamingRecognizeRequest.newBuilder().setAudioContent(tempByteString).build();

            audioInput.add(tempByteString);
          }
          clientStream.send(request);
          if(breakTranscription) {
              clientStream.closeSend();
              break;
          }
          
        }
      } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When setting language code to en-IN only the partial transcripts are produced but they are no good.
I tried setting alternate languages also by passing languageCode="en-US" and adding "en-IN" and "hi-IN" in alternate language list but that started producing transcripts in hindi even when i was speaking in english. what am i doing wrong can someone help.